# How To Execute PowerShell via WinRM

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, winrm

Env:

```
Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation  
version 1607(OSbuild 14393.2248)
```

my_powershell.ps1 is below.

```
echo $args
```

In local I can execute above script.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> .\echo_args.ps1 "aaaa"
aaaa
```

And I can execute command or exe files via winrm.
e.g)

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrs -r:localhost -u:Administrator -p:MyPassword .\my.exe
```

But when I execute my_powershell.ps1 via WinRM(below), my_powershell.ps1 has been waiting, without doing something.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrs -r:localhost -u:Administrator -p:MyPassword .\echo_args.ps1
```

My WinRM config is below.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrm get winrm/config
    Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
    Basic = true
    Digest = true
    Kerberos = true
    Negotiate = true
    Certificate = true
    CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
    HTTP = 5985
    HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = *
    Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2048
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

Where should I chanage?

Comment: why are you using WinRS.exe? that starts a remote CMD shell, from what i recall. the usual method is to use `Invoke-Command` ...

Comment: I want to do that, on remote linux server do my windows program with pywinrm to connect.I tried to do execute my .exe  but, charcode problem occured when I use Japanese, so now I'm trying to wrap PowerShell and convert charcode.

Comment: thank you for the "why" of it. i appreciate the info ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

My command of winrm was wrong. When executing PowerShell via WinRm, I should specify to use PowerShell.exe.

So right command is below.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrs -r:localhost -u:Administrator -p:MyPassword powershell .\echo_args.ps1 "aaaa"
```